# Functionally setting Leaflet marker colors by a property for geojson data

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

Similarly to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43613560/changing-marker-colour-based-on-property-in-leaflet), we want to functionally set our Leaflet map's marker's colors based off a value, except our map is built with geojson data.

We want markers' colors to be functional to `color_value` (eg. different shade of green), but we don't know how to build that like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43613631) explains with `L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({markerColor: determineColor(rating)});`, because the markers for all our entries are built at once with `pointToLayer: function (feature, coordinates) {return L.marker(coordinates, { icon: customicon });}`. Simplified eg:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
    html,
    body { margin: 0px; height: 100%; }
    body {display: flex;}
</style>

<body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
        integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
        crossorigin="" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
        integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
        crossorigin=""></script>
    <div id="mapid" style="flex: 1"></div>
    <script>var myMap = L.map("mapid");
        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(myMap);
        myMap.setView([51.5, -0.09], 10);

        var geojsonFeatureCollection =
        {
            "type": "FeatureCollection",
            "features": [{
                "type": "Feature",
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [-0.09, 51.5]
                },
                "properties": {
                    "color_value": 1
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [-0.4, 51.5]
                },
                "properties": {
                    "color_value": 10
                }
            }]
        }

        const myCustomColor = '#007a83'
        const markerHtmlStyles = `
  background-color: ${myCustomColor};  width: 1.3rem;  height: 1.3rem;  display: block;`
        const customicon = L.divIcon({html: `<span style="${markerHtmlStyles}" />`})

        L.geoJSON(geojsonFeatureCollection, {
            pointToLayer: function (feature, coordinates) {
                return L.marker(coordinates, { icon: customicon });
            }
        })
            .addTo(myMap);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

We've found [this tutorial](http://gauteheggen.com/adding-custom-coloured-markers-in-leaflet-maps/) which gets us a little closer by explaining how to choose different markers based off some value, but we want to set the color itself, not choose from existing markers.

How can we make `myCustomColor` functional to `color_value`, or otherwise set marker colors programmatically for geojson data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there! :-)

You can define the desired color directly as a property on each GeoJSON feature. Leaflet passes each feature of the GeoJSON collection to `pointToLayer`, allowing you to access its properties.

Check out the snippet below.

```js
var myMap = L.map("mapid");

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(myMap);

myMap.setView([51.5, -0.09], 10);

var geojsonFeatureCollection = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-0.09, 51.5]
      },
      "properties": {
        // You can define a different color for each property
        // and access it in pointToLayer().
        "color_value": '#007a83'
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-0.4, 51.5]
      },
      "properties": {
        // Here I might use a different color
        "color_value": '#003134'
      }
    }
  ]
};

L.geoJSON(geojsonFeatureCollection, {
    pointToLayer: function(feature, coordinates) {
      // Leaflet passes each GeoJSON feature in the collection in here,
      // allowing you to access the feature's properties
      const color_value = feature.properties.color_value;

      // With the color obtained from the properties, you can now create
      // the marker icon with the correct color.
      const markerHtmlStyles = `background-color: ${color_value};  width: 1.3rem;  height: 1.3rem;  display: block;`;

      const customicon = L.divIcon({
        html: `<span style="${markerHtmlStyles}" />`
      });

      return L.marker(coordinates, {
        icon: customicon
      });
    },
  })
  .addTo(myMap);
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin="" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA==" crossorigin=""></script>
  <div id="mapid" style="flex: 1"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Alternatively, if you want to calculate the color based off `color_value`, you can proceed almost the same way: Read `color_value` property inside `pointToLayer`, generate the color (e.g., by using an approach like the one outlined here: [Programmatically Lighten or Darken a hex color (or rgb, and blend colors)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560248/programmatically-lighten-or-darken-a-hex-color-or-rgb-and-blend-colors/13542669#13542669)) and pass it to your marker's styling.

Hope this helps!